# HyperlinkField in Gridview not showing blue underline for links

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-3.5

I have a hyperlinkfield in Gridview control. I am using the below shown stylesheet for the gridview.
But for some reason, the hyperlinkField column in the gridview is not in blue color and there is no underline.

How can I display the hyperlinks as regular hyperlinks as blue in color and underline?

Thanks

```
/* table style */
table.BlueGridView
{

    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    border:solid 1px #7aa5d6;

    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10pt;

    /*position:fixed; */
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    direction: ltr;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

/* header cell style */
.BlueGridView th
{
    color:#3366cc;
    border-right-color:#7aa5d6;
    border-bottom-color:#7aa5d6;
    background:#e5ecf9;
}  

/* cell styles */
.BlueGridView td
{
    border-bottom-color:#e5ecf9;    
    border-right-color:#e5ecf9; 
}

/* mouseover row style */
.BlueGridView .row-over 
{ 
    background-color:#e5ecf9;
}
/* Alternating Row Color */
.BlueGridView .alt-data-row 
{ 
    background-color:#e5ecf9;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:small; 

}

.BlueGridView .data-row
{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:small; 
}

.BlueGridView .selected-row
{
    background-color:Blue;  
}

/* GridView Header */
.BlueGridView .header-row
{
    color: #000080;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center; 
    /* position:relative; */



}

/* mouse select row style */
.BlueGridView .row-select 
{ 
    background-color:#7aa5d6;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: You should also post your GridView code, otherwise it's really difficult to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Use FireBug to determine which CSS rules applies last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your entire style sheet and GridView code, this is the best answer I can give you.

```
.BlueGridView * a
{
    text-decoration:underline !important;
    color: #0000F5 !important;
}
```

This effects all  tags in the .BlueGridView ... so if you have other hyperlinks, be more specific with the selector.